# Difference between vulkan queue families

Tags: graphics, gpu, vulkan

I'm fairly new to vulkan, and am playing around with the api. I have a function that prints my queue families, and currently I have two:

One that supports graphics/transfer/compute, with a max of 16 queues,
and one that supports sparse/transfer with a max of 2 queues.

Say I want to create two queues, one for graphics and one for transfer only. My understanding is that a transfer queue created out of the first family is effectively identical to one created out of the second family, as long as I only use transfer operations. AKA, I can pretty much ignore the second family as long as I do not use sparse memory operations.

Is this understanding correct, or am I missing something. Is there some reason that I would prefer to make my graphics and transfer queues from separate families?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among the properties of a queue family include `minImageTransferGranularity`. This is a limitation on the XYZ regions of image data that can be copied using this queue family. So if this value is 8x8x8, then the location and size of pixel rectangle copies must be aligned on 8-pixel boundaries for all image copy operations on that queue.

So no, you cannot assume that a transfer-only queue family can always be used in place of a more capable queue. You always have to check.

At the same time, dedicated transfer queue families tend to represent specialized hardware specifically intended for doing transfer operations. So they may be using more efficient data pathways than transfer operations on other queues.

Generally speaking, if a piece of hardware offers a queue that *only* does transfer work, and you're doing enough transfer work that you're considering using a dedicated queue for it, you should use *that* queue family for doing transfer work (so long as the granularity works out for you).